# Why might Internet explorer return different results when running as a windows service?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-8, windows-services

I have a Windows Service that is calling a Web Page via the ShDocVw object (IE8) with a URL. It then checks the page and if it gets a certain result, it reads the data and then returns a result.

When I run this in debug and as my ordinary domain user, it all works happily. When I run it as an ordinary domain user as a Windows Service, it gives me back a completely different web page. I have checked the calling URL and the response URL from the web page and in debug or in production and they are exactly the same! Strangely, the web page being sent back in debug is different to the one being sent back in production. The one in debug gives me the information that I am looking for, but the production version (running as a Windows Service) responds with an error.

The original URL seems to be redirecting to another web page, which is why I am using ShDocVw and IE for the process (unless someone tells me otherwise). I did try using a different object, but I cannot remember what that was now.

What is really weird is that the process works perfectly for 3 different URLs in debug and in the Windows Service, but the fourth URL varies it's returned web page (but has the same URL)!

The code is something like:

```
        InternetExplorer objIE = new InternetExplorer();
        objIE.Navigate(sService, ref objEmpty, ref objEmpty, ref objEmpty, ref objEmpty);
        while (objIE.Busy || (objIE.ReadyState.ToString() != "READYSTATE_COMPLETE"))
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (i == I_TIMEOUT)
            {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        mshtml.HTMLDocument objDocument = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)objIE.Document;
```

Does anyone know how to find out what the problem is or know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you logged on to one of the websites?

Comment: What URL's are you trying?

Comment: why the need to use a InternetExplorer to perform a webrequest..can you just the WebRequest class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx

Comment: There is a lot missing from your question.  First off I would **never** consider using ShDocVw within a service to navigate to a site.  We have much better tools as Mauricio suggested.  Second, what do you mean by "the fourth URL varies it's returned values!".  In what way is it different?  Please edit your question and put in what you expected and what you received.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the problem was that the USER that the Windows Service was running under had never been logged on, so it did not have an IE profile. Once I logged onto the computer as the user and fire up and close IE, the Windows Service started to work and the correct request then resulted in the correct response for the previously errant request.

Thanks for your answers.